# Avoiding duplicate row entry inside django model

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I have a `CarRent` model that is a ForeignKey to the `Car` model. On the `Car` detailView page i have a button for drivers to place a Rent which will result in adding a row to the CarRent Table. The rent isn’t active yet until the Car owner approves the rent request. The problem now is that a driver could click the rent button multiple times thereby resulting in many duplicate rows in the `CarRent` model and also multiple redundant car rent request to the car owner. I am looking for a way to hide the “Place A Rent” form if the current user (driver) has already requested for a particular car and rent_approval is not True.

Thanks. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

models.py

```
class Car(models.Model):
    
    car_owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='car_owner', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    car_model = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    rented = models.BooleanField(default=False)



class CarRent(models.Model):

    car = models.ForeignKey(Car, related_name='rented_car', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    driver = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='driver_renting', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rent_approval = models.BooleanField(null=True)
    active_rent = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True)
```

views.py

```
class CarView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, FormMixin, DetailView):
    model = Car
    form_class = RentForm

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('app:car-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.get_form()
        self.object = self.get_object()

        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)

    def form_valid(self, form, *args, **kwargs):
        form.instance.car_id = self.kwargs['pk']
        form.instance.driver = self.request.user
        form.save()
        messages.success(self.request, f'Rent request successful! the car owner will be notified immediately.')
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def test_func(self):
        return self.request.user.is_driver and self.request.user.is_active
```

car_detail.html

```
...
<h3>Place a Rent</h3>
                <form action="" method="post" novalidate class="form-inline">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                
                    {% include 'app/bs4_form.html' with form=form %}
                
                <button class="book-now-btn" type="submit">Rent</button>
                </form>


...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your CarView class:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['rentAlreadyExists'] = CarRent.objects.filter(driver=self.request.user, car=self.object, active_rent=False).exists()
    return context
```

Then in your template you can do:

```
{% if not rentAlreadyExists %}
... your form ...
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a proper solution you can define a inner Meta class for CarRent and define a unique_together attirbute for fields driver and car to avoid duplicate entry.

```
class CarRent(models.Model):

    car = models.ForeignKey(Car, related_name='rented_car', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    driver = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='driver_renting', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rent_approval = models.BooleanField(null=True)
    active_rent = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True)
    
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("driver", "car")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the problem i have with that solution is that that will prevent the same driver from renting same car in the future. They should be able to rent the same car in the future after their current rent has expired.

Answer (score 0):

So that is a valid problem. For that you may have to provide the validation by overriding the save function for CarRent.

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
   
   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        has_reservation = self.__class__.objects.filter(car=self.car, driver=self.driver)
        #reservation_valid =  some logic to find if reservation is allowed
        if not reservation_valid:
            raise ValidationError("Driver reservation is not valid", code="drive_not_valid")
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Then in the view

```
try:
   #try renting
except Exception as e:
   if hasattr(e, "code"):
      if e.code == "drive_not_valid":
         #place your invalid view logic here
```